# 2 iFrames with different heights appear the same size when put on the same page

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have two separate `<iframe>` tags that are on the same page.

They are both in a `<container>` div and each `<iframe>` only shows a portion of each page.

The problem is when I try to put both of them on the same page, the bottom `<iframe>` is the same height as the top `<iframe>` even though I set the height of each `<iframe>` explicitly.

Even though each `<iframe>` is set to a different height, when I try to put both of them together, it messes things up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    <!--
      #container{
        width: 380px;
        height: 360px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      #container iframe {
        width: 600px;
        height: 475px;
        margin-left: -15px;
        margin-top: -90px;  
        border: 0;
      }
    -->
  </style>
  <div id="container">
    <iframe height="200" scrolling="no" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?hl=en_US&amp;formkey=dHJjVk94bExPMmxtaExmX1FSckpicGc6MQ#gid=0" width="600">  
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    <!--
      #container {
        width: 400px;
        height: 65px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      #container iframe {
        width: 600px;
        height: 675px;
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-top: -350px;  
        border: 0;
      }
    -->
  </style>

  <div id="container">
    <iframe height="200" scrolling="no" src="http://scores.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=310818027" width="600">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The value for the id attribute for any element in the same html document must be unique.  You should not have two `<div>` elements with the id of `container` on the same page.

If you needed two elements to have similar styles, you could use the same class attribute on each of them.

In this case, you are looking to have different styles, so my recommendation would be to change the ids for each container div.

**HTML:**

```
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
  <title></title>
  <div id="spreadsheet">
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?hl=en_US&amp;formkey=dHJjVk94bExPMmxtaExmX1FSckpicGc6MQ#gid=0" width="600">  
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
  <title></title> 
  <div id="scores">
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="http://scores.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=310818027">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#spreadsheet{
     width: 380px;
     height: 360px;
     overflow: hidden;
}

#spreadsheet iframe {
        width: 600px;
        height: 470px;
        margin-left: -5px;
        margin-top: -80px;  
        border: 0;
      }

      #scores {
        width: 400px;
        height: 65px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      #scores iframe {
        width: 600px;
        height: 685px;
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-top: -375px;  
        border: 0;
      }
```

**Note:**

The **CSS** should ideally be placed in a separate document at a different URL and referred to in a `<link>` tag in the `<head>` section of your HTML document.  If you need to have the styles inline, it is a best practice to include them in the `<head>` section of the document inside a `<style>` tag.

I've put an example of these changes in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwolfetech/AWVmj/).